# Move Attachement from Task to Lead/Account Parent Id

Tags: apex, trigger, attachment, account

i am using email to salesforce, here, whenever an customer is sending email to a specific email it will be automatically forwarded to email to salesforce email. Then the email will be added as a Task to either Lead or Contact, whereever the emailaddress from the customer is linked to.

Now, all attachements are only saved to the Task but I would like to attach them to the Parent Object, such as Lead or Account, is that possible by writing a trigger on Attachement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since the **ParentId** field is not updatable, I don't think you will be able to do this by just updating the existing attachment. You may need some cloning.

Comment: Yes I suggested to insert the attachment instead of updating.

Comment: Rajeev, what do you mean by inserting instead of updating? Can you maybe check my trigger for any mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The attachment should be attached to the Task's Parent object just after the Task is created by email to Salesforce. Hence the trigger should be on task. You can write an "after insert" trigger on Task that will fetch the attachments of the task in context and attach the same attachment to the Parent Object.

- Capture Id and WhatId of the inserted task. You will have both of them since the trigger is on after insert.
- Use Id field to query from Attachment object. Like this:

  ```
  List<Attachment> att = [Select Id, Body from Attachment where ParentId = :IdOfInsertedTask];
  ```
- Now, since you have the attachments you can simply insert the attachment with ParentId equal to WhatId of the task. The trigger should be able to handle bulk records. Hence you will have to use Maps to keep up the correct mapping of Task -> Attachemnt and Attachment->Parent object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick replies,

i found a trigger, which works for Accounts as follwing:

```
trigger CheckforAttachement on Attachment (before insert) {
    //Check to see if the Attachment has a Task as the Parent Record
   for (Attachment a : trigger.new){
       String parentIdString = String.valueof(a.parentId);
    if (parentIdString.substring(0,3) == '00T'){
        //Select the AccountId from the Task
        task parent = [SELECT AccountId FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :a.parentId];
        //Check to see if the Account exists
        if (parent.AccountID != null){
            //Select the Attachment body (it isn't in memory for an update)
            Attachment body = [SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :a.Id];
            //Create a new Attachment, preserving as much as is possible
            Attachment newA = New Attachment(
                Name = a.Name,
                Body = body.Body,
                OwnerId = a.OwnerId,
                ParentId = parent.AccountId
            );
            //Insert the new Attachment
            insert newA;
        }}
    }
}


when i tried to adopt this to LeadID as following, it doesn´t work, any ideas why?

trigger MoveAttToLead on Attachment (after insert) {
 //Check to see if the Attachment has a Task as the Parent Record
   for (Attachment a : trigger.new){
       String parentIdString = String.valueof(a.parentId);
    if (parentIdString.substring(0,3) == '00T'){
        //Select the LeadId from the Task
        task parent = [SELECT WhoID FROM Task WHERE WhoId = :a.parentId];
        //Check to see if the Account exists
        if (parent.WhoID != null){
            //Select the Attachment body (it isn't in memory for an update)
            Attachment body = [SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :a.Id];
            //Create a new Attachment, preserving as much as is possible
            Attachment newA = New Attachment(
                Name = a.Name,
                Body = body.Body,
                OwnerId = a.OwnerId,
                ParentId = parent.WhoID
            );
            //Insert the new Attachment
            insert newA;
        }}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

now, after lots of different testings etc... i finally made the following trigger, which works totally great. feel free to share.

let me quickly summarize the background of this, I am activating email to salesforce, so if customers sending emails in, they will automatically attached to either relevant Lead or Account. Unfortunately, the attachment is usually saved to the Task but this doesn´t help our complaint and customer service center, as they want the attachments saved to the parent object, such as Lead or Account, so with the following trigger, it´s doing totally, what I expected, as well as deleting the attachment from task to avoid double attachments.

> trigger MoveAtt on Attachment (after insert) {

```
List<Id> forDeletionIds = new List<Id>();
for (Attachment a : trigger.new){
String parentIdString = String.valueof(a.parentId);
if (parentIdString.substring(0,3) == '00T'){
    System.debug(a.parentId);
    if(Task.WhatId != null){
        task parent1 = [SELECT Id,WhatId  FROM Task WHERE Id = :a.parentId];
    if (parent1.WhatId  != null){
        Attachment body = [SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :a.Id];
        Attachment newA = New Attachment(
            Name = a.Name,
            Body = body.Body,
            Description = 'Email Attachment from ' + date.today(),
            OwnerId = a.OwnerId,
            ParentId = parent1.WhatId
        );
    }
    task parent = [SELECT Id,WhoId  FROM Task WHERE Id = :a.parentId];
    if (parent.WhoId  != null){
        Attachment body = [SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :a.Id];
        Attachment newA = New Attachment(
            Name = a.Name,
            Body = body.Body,
            Description = 'Email Attachment from ' + date.today(),
            OwnerId = a.OwnerId,
            ParentId = parent.WhoId
        );
        insert newA;
        forDeletionIds.add(a.Id);
    }
  }
}List<Attachment> forDeletion = [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE Id IN :forDeletionIds];delete forDeletion;
}}
```